# IntelliJ debugging of Android using waitForDebugger

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ 11.1.3 developing an application against a galaxy nexus running android 4.1.1

Without selecting the "Debug" invocation option, can one use the pattern

```
Debug.waitForDebugger()
```

Followed by a breakpoint to break into the code?

What I'm finding is that I can see that my app is waiting for the debugger (red icon in DDMS) but intellij never shows the debugger.

Is there any way that this can be done without using the Debug (as opposed to Run) invocation?

Comment: Did you try `Attach debugger to Android process`? This way you can debug only when you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is from CrazyCoder above - once you hit the waitForDebugger then you click on the Attach Debugger to Android Process.[image: Screenshot]